# PHP project: Telnet connection to Nokia Equipements(MSS) with PHP and data interaction with database throught telnet

Tags: php, database, telnet

As part of my graduation project, I have to make a `web application` that connects to a Nokia proprietary equipment.
This is the architecture of my project.

- Is it possible to do this project with to language `PHP`: Can I connect to the equipment with php throught telnet
- and for the hand "1" Can the database through php interact with the equipment with telnet

Just to know I had never developed any thing in php, even with developing web applications.

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: I believe your architecture should be looking like a star with web application in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP telnet library available you can use that.Refer the link below [http://www.geckotribe.com/php-telnet/](http://telnet)

Comment: Thanks for your response                                                                          1-I saw the link in fact the connection I received connected but after that a strange character                                                                                            2-The connection stay so long to give the reponse3

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, You cannot have a `Web application` in PHP connection to telnet. The reason being the server that runs in front (Apache/nginx) calls the PHP script every time there is a request and has a default timeout period. So the telnet connection would be blocking for your webpage.
Now from what i understand is that you are trying to build a PHP application and you want some telnet connection to render/store in database. The correct way from my point of view to do this would be to make two applications, One is your PHP website and the other can be a wrapper around telnet server. The telnet application would run as a service unlike Php app because u need to maintain the connection. As far as the fetching the telnet data into php app/ dbs there could be many method. I am listing some of them for you.

1. Process pipes in php to interact with telnet app
2. Make a wrapper web service around telnet and use curl in php to fetch info
3. [Recommended if you want it in dbs] Directly add content from the telnet app into the database.

The above answer is if you only want to use PHP to make the app. If thats not the case have a look at GNU microhttpd server, That can be used to do what you are trying with much more control

Comment: Thank you for your response.In fact, I re clear my idea in another way: I have to develop a web application that connects to the equipment through Telnet protocol, collects the information needed then stock them into a database then consult the database an take the information that I need to make some statics.
I did some research I found sockets in PHP I tried some codes but when I execute them it's stay too long and I am not sure if it is right. Shall I continue in this way or try another language Like JEE or.NET?
Which is the appropriate language for this project. Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi the language can be anything, Even PHP as it supports sockets. The problem is that you have to make a webpage and in php with apache/nginx it makes it a little complicated because the script is called everytime and has a timeout. What i would recommend is that if you have experience in c++ go with that or python if you have just started. Now these two languages are only for telnet. You can save that data in database for PHP site to access which would be simpler. Another way could be using a Pub/Sub method like ZMQ but i would recommend to keep things simpler to avoid confusion. :)